# Input string was not in a correct format for line

Tags: c#, int, string-conversion

i want to download a file from grid view for specific user.but error is Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format for line

```
int ID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[index].Value);
```

Comment: make sure `GridView1.DataKeys[index].Value` value is convertible to int..

Comment: Whoever upvoted the question could you please add what is the value of `GridView1.DataKeys[index].Value`?

Comment: what is the value of `DataKeys` at your `index` does it supposed to be an integer or you are trying to `Convert` some other `DataKey` as `Name` etc??

Comment: when i select user id from dropdown list .the files of that user are displayed in grid view but when i click on download button in gridview it give the error . Input string was not in a correct format for line for int ID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[index].Value);

Comment: @user3428233 We understand how it is supposed to work. What we really need is to know the values of your `GridView1.DataKeys`. Edit your question and add the code where you load the `GridView1` with data so we can have a look and help you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the DataKey retrieved from the grid is not a valid integer. Try this,

```
int index = 0; // Maybe the current row index
var idString = GridView1.DataKeys[index].Value as string;
int ID;
if(idString != null && int.TryParse(idString, out ID))
{
  // The value present in the grid is not valid integer value.
  throw new Exception("DataKey is not a valid integer."); 
}
```

Comment: And how exactly is this supposed to help? The OP is already getting an exception, and you've replaced it with another exception. How helpful! However, if you replace your exception line with a nice message to the user, then there is the benefit of not crashing, but still not an answer.

Comment: I don't know what needs to be done if the DataKey is not a valid integer. Thats why I thrown an exception. He can do what needs to be done instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: Yes, I know that and that's what I said. The point is: your code does not offer him anything except handling the exception. That's not neither a solution nor an answer. He asked for help in fixing his issue. Only once that's done, your code can be used as an enhancement.